# Is there an efficient way of creating a list of tuples using a range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I'm seeking for an efficient way to combine a number range like `(20,24)` with another object like `{'a': 'b'}` to get,

```py
[(20, {'a': 'b'}), (21, {'a': 'b'}), (22, {'a': 'b'}), (23, {'a': 'b'})]
```

If I had a list of numbers like `[20, 21, 22, 23]`, I know iterating through the list is the way to go. But here I have a range of numbers. So may be there is a way to wrap range elements in tuples more elegantly.

Here is my attempt to achieve this:

```py
min = 20
max = 23
data = {"a": "b"}
result = []
for i in range(min, max + 1):
    result.append((i, data))
print(result)
```

I just want to know whether there is any better way to do this.

Comment: `[(x, data) for x in range(20, 24)]`? Keep in mind that you are only duplicating the reference. Change one dict and they all change.

Comment: That's neat, but being "better" is questionable ;)

Comment: Bear in mind that, in all these cases, a change `data["a"] = "z"` will affect every element of `result`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, any for loop appending to an empty list can be transformed into a list comprehension.

```
l = []
for x in range(20, 24):
    l.append((x, data))
```

Or,

```
l = [(x, data) for x in range(20, 24)]
```

*However*! Note that what you get is this -

```
for i in l:
     print(id(i[1]))

4835204232
4835204232
4835204232
4835204232
```

Where the same object being reference-copied multiple times. This is a problem with mutable objects, because if you change one object, they all reflect the change. Because of this, I'd recommend making a *copy* of your data at each step. You can either use the builtin `dict.copy` function, or a function from the `copy` module. In the former case, only a shallow copy is done, so if you have a nested structure, that isn't a good idea.

Anyway, this is how I'd do it -

```
import copy
l = [(x, copy.deepcopy(data)) for x in range(20, 24)]
```

If your dictionary isn't complex in structure (for example - `{'a' : {'b' : 'c'}}`), the `dict.copy` method that I mentioned above works -

```
l = [(x, data.copy()) for x in range(20, 24)]
```

Comment: Should that not be `print(id(i[1]))` (e.g. `i` instead of `l`)?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie Indeed. It was a copy paste error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

A fun way is to go with zip i.e

```
mini = 20
maxi = 24
data = {'a':'b'}
l = range(mini,maxi)

list(zip(l,[data]*len(l)))

[(20, {'a': 'b'}), (21, {'a': 'b'}), (22, {'a': 'b'}), (23, {'a': 'b'})]
```

Comment: Note that this still suffers from the problem outlined in my answer. Still, upvoted for thinking out of the box.

Comment: Yeap yeap yeap I got it, removed the comment

Comment: You can, however eliminate this using `copy`, so this is still a valid answer once you fix that.

Answer (score 4):

`itertools.repeat` offers a clean way to do this.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> min = 20
>>> max = 23
>>> data = {"a": "b"}
>>> 
>>> list(zip(range(min, max+1), repeat(data)))
[(20, {'a': 'b'}), (21, {'a': 'b'}), (22, {'a': 'b'}), (23, {'a': 'b'})]
```

Note that the dictionary `{'a':'b'}` - or each object which you `repeat` - will be the same object in memory in each of the tuples with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
mins = 20
maxs = 23
data = {'a': 'b'}
print([(x, data) for x in range(mins, maxs + 1)])
# [(20, {'a': 'b'}), (21, {'a': 'b'}), (22, {'a': 'b'}), (23, {'a': 'b'})]
```

Or you can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map) here aswell:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: (x, data), range(mins, maxs + 1))))
# [(20, {'a': 'b'}), (21, {'a': 'b'}), (22, {'a': 'b'}), (23, {'a': 'b'})]
```

**Note:** In your version, you use `max` and `min` as variable names. This isn't a good idea since they are already builtin functions. Use different variable names instead.

Additionally, as others have mentioned, the dictionary you wish to repeat will be the same object in memory throughout all the tuples. You can fix this problem with @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's informative answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's always a better way than appending to an empty list. You can convert any expression of the form

```
result = []
for i in iterable:
    result.append(something)
```

to a list comprehension

```
result = [something for i in iterable]
```

That makes the core of your code pretty simple.